# Provision a GCP regional instance group via Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am exploring managed instance groups on GCP, and I am trying to create a multi-zone (regional) MIG. The instance template gets created however, it always fails to create the MIG declaring a permission error below:

[image]

Below is the associated service account used to provision the MIG:
[image]

and this is the default service account of Compute Engine:
[image]

since I'm using Cloud build, this the default SA:

[image]

I highly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Are you sute TF is using that SA to create the MIGs? Isn't there any other restrictions?

Comment: Everything works fine except for the MIG, I thought about the Compute Engine Instance Group Manager API, but it's already enabled on the project